# How did Peter Quill pay for the prosthetic leg at the Kyln?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

In *Guardians of the Galaxy (2014)* movie, when Rocket Raccoon explains his escape plan to the others, he demands few things from the others: the **security bands worn by the prison guards**, a **prosthetic leg** of a fellow prisoner and **a quarnyx battery**.

> **Rocket:** *If we're gonna get out of here, we're gonna need to get into that watchtower. And to do that,*
>   *I'm gonna need a few things.*
>
> *The guards wear security bands to control their ins and outs. I need one.*
>
> **Gamora:** *Leave it to me.*
>
> **Rocket:** *That dude, there.*
>
> *I need his prosthetic leg.*
>
> **Quill:** *His leg?*
>
> Rocket: *Yeah.*
>
> *God knows I don't need the rest of him.*
>
> *Look at him, he's useless.*
>
> **Quill:** *All right.*
>
> **Rocket:** *And finally, on the wall back there is a black panel. Blinky yellow light.*
>
> *Do you see it?*
>
> **Quill:** *Yeah.*
>
> **Rocket:** *There's a quarnyx battery behind it. Purplish box, green wires. To get into that watchtower, I definitely need it.*

Quill takes up the task to get the leg and (*although it's off-screen*), Quill ends up paying 30,000 units to trade the guy's prosthetic leg.

> **Rocket:** *No, I thought it'd be funny.*
>
> *Was it funny? Wait, what did he look like hopping around?*
>
> **Quill:** *I had to transfer him 30,000 units!*

As they were all in prison, how and when did Quill get access to his "**galactic**" bank account to pay for the leg?

Comment: Maybe it's an open jail with a commissary

Comment: Maybe he has intergalactic telephone banking

Comment: It's prison. You can get anything in prison.

Comment: At a guess, Peter has an implanted chip used for payment and money transfers. It is a technology that is being experimented with IRL.

Comment: The guards may well have been happy for every prisoner in there to have access to their money. Inmates without cash can’t bribe you!

Comment: It's not earth prison. If he can transfer the money in the space prison then he can transfer them.

Comment: I remember seeing something about how there was an implant that can transfer units... sort of like an ID chip? But it's possible that Prosthetic Leg Man had a credit card reader of sorts but for space. Or there could have been something with the guards.

Comment: Naughty favors?